# Splitting an array with commas to separate each elemnt

Tags: java, arrays, element

I have an output that comes out printing : 1 2 3 4 5
I want the output to be : 1,2,3,4,5
When I print my final array, It looks like : System.out.println(D);
What should I add to it to suit my needs.
All answers are welcome.

Comment: if you have: String t = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"; you can do String v = t.replace(" ", ","); and System.out.println(v); It would give you: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not simply use Arrays.toString

> public static String toString(int[] a) Returns a string representation
>   of the contents of the specified array. The string representation
>   consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square
>   brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ",
>   " (a comma followed by a space). Elements are converted to strings as
>   by String.valueOf(int). Returns "null" if a is null. Parameters: a -
>   the array whose string representation to return Returns: a string
>   representation of a Since:
>   1.5

try

```
System.out.println (Arrays.toString (D));
```

if the spaces are unwanted, then they can be `replaced` using

```
System.out.println (Arrays.toString (D).replace(" ", ""));
```

Comment: Because OP doesn't want ", " as separator but rather just ",". Using `Arrays.toString` makes the code harder to change in the future.

Comment: @Atsby Noted your commented about spaces and have offered a fix for this.  By using a standard library call, it is **less** error prone than hand-crafted code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(typeof x)` with the element type of the array (or put this code in a generic function for bonus points, but it won't work for primitive types then):

```
StringBuilder out = (new StringBuilder());

boolean first = true;

for ((typeof x) x : D) {
  if (!first) { 
    out.append(",")
  }

  out.append(x.toString());

  first = false;
}

return out.toString();
```

Comment: Will this work for arrays too, and is there any simpler ways that I can just add to my system.out.print?

Comment: Yes, it will work for arrays (`D` is the array). The same code will also work for any `Enumerable` type, including, for example, `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create you own methods for printing the result, for example this one :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < D.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(D[i]);
        if (i != D.length-1){
            System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to print out an array with commas instead of spaces.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length() - 1; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i]);
    System.out.print(',');
}
System.out.println(arr[arr.length() - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just print out the elements of the Array singly, like this:

```
String output = "";
//go through all elements in D
for (int i =0;i<D.length;i++){
    //add the Integer to the String
    output = output+i;
    //add , if not the last element
    if (i<D.length-1){
        output = output+",";
    }
}
//Print it out
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

If your data type is an array of integer:

```
int my_array={1,2,3,4,5};

for(int i=0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(my_array[i] + ",");//this line will print the value with a coma (,)
}
```

If your data type is a string;

```
String my_number="1 2 3 4 5";

for(int i=0; i < my_number.length; i++){
    if(my_number.toCharArray()[i]!=' ')
       System.out.print(my_number.toCharArray()[i]+",");
}
```

Or,

```
String my_number="1 2 3 4 5";
my_number = my_number.replace(' ', ',');//this method (replace) will replace all space(' ') by coma(',')
System.out.println(my_number);
```